# Signs of Matlab and Numpy Graph Fourier Transform Matrix are Different

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, math, graph

I would like to ask why I see the same numerical results but with different signs for the same demo data. I understand that the signs are arbitrary, but I'm using the transpose of this matrix in later implementation and getting severly different results over iterations because of the sign difference. Thus, I really need the Python GFT to match.

Python:

```
import math

import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import scipy.sparse as sp
from math import gcd, pi
import cmath
...
adj = dict['adj']  # given adj matrix
D = sp.diags(np.array(adj.sum(axis=0)).flatten())
# print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(D.toarray()))
L = D - adj  # Laplacian matrix
eigenvalues, psi_gft = np.linalg.eigh(L.toarray())
# sort eigenvalues by ascending order such that constant vector is in first column
idx = np.argsort(np.abs(eigenvalues))
eigenvalues = eigenvalues[idx]
psi_gft = psi_gft[:, idx]
```

Numpy 7x7 table:

[image]

Matlab:

```
L=diag(sum(adj))-adj;
[PsiGFT,e]= eigs(L, 175, 'sm');
```

Matlab 7x7 table:

[image]

Note that these 7x7 tables are just samples as the size of the matrices is 175x200.

As you can notice, the absolute values of the 7x7 sample matrices are equivalent, but I'm seeing different signs in some cells. I was wondering what I can do to the Python implementation to match the Matlab implementation.

I tried using the Numpy implementation of the eigh method but I am getting the occasional opposite sign. I am expecting the matrices to match perfectly between Python and Matlab, given it is the same demo data.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of questions on here about the eigendecomposition not producing the same results in MATLAB and Python. I encourage you to search for that.

Comment: Please include your Python imports and the actual text for the 7x7 matrices so people can test the code.

Comment: Hi @jared, the only imports are numpy and scipy. The matrix in question is 175x200 but I just highlighted the first 7 rows/columns to show the sign differences.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo, I searched through quite a few threads and haven’t found anything like the issue I’m dealing with. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPaglia it doesn't look like you're just importing numpy and SciPy since `scipy.diags` doesn't exist (at least I don't think it does). There is `scipy.sparse.diags`, but is your matrix sparse? Why not use `np.linalg.diags`? In general, I recommend including all your imports rather than leaving us to guess.

Comment: Hi @jared, I've updated my post to include imports to better assist. Apologies for the confusion and appreciate the response.

Comment: @MichaelPaglia (1) please only include the imports relevant to the question. (2) is your matrix sparse that you're using `scipy.sparse.diags`?

Comment: Hi @jared, according to the Matlab code, the Laplacian matrix (L=diag(sum(adj))-adj;) is a sparse double.